# What is the practical value of the 'scale' parameter in Hspice '.trannoise' command?

Tags: hspice

HSpice transient noise simulation command '.trannoise' has the following parameters:

*.TRANNOISE output [METHOD=MC] [SEED=val] [START=val] [FMIN=val] [FMAX=val] **[SCALE=val]** [AUTOCORRELATION=0|1|2|off|on] [PHASENOISE=0|1|2] [REF=srcName]*

As far as I know, the 'scale' parameter here indicates how strong the effect of noise will be. As I am new to using HSpice, I don't know what the practical value of this parameter is. Is it 1? If I set it to 10, will it be impractical?